# How to remove following symbol/special character in string using jquery ¶

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove following symbol/special character in string using jquery

¶

I have problem during comparing two strings .
Above mentioned symbol is append when I compute difference.
I also test it in my local application
please check link below.

http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var s = "This is a string that contains ¶, a special character.";
s = s.replace(/¶/g, "");
```

Yields:

```
"This is a string that contains , a special character."
```

This will remove all occurrences of the character.  No jQuery necessary - just vanilla browser-provided JavaScript.

Some additional details are available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery isn't needed for this, you can achieve it by using native javascripts `replace` function:

```
var myString = "ABC¶DEFG"
alert(myString.replace("¶", ""))
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PzW3N/)

Comment: May I suggest, instead: [`alert(myString.replace(/¶/g,''));`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PzW3N/1/) otherwise only the *first* matched character is removed from/replaced in the string.

Comment: Good point David. I'll leave this as-is as ziesemer has covered it in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

javascript replace function should work.  If it isn't finding the character then try using the unicode or ansi equivalent.

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html